# storyboard viewcontroller to coded viewcontroller

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Is it possible to connect Storyboard ViewControllers with manual code-written ViewControllers? What I'm trying to do is make an app that, when internet connection is established, I see the viewcontroller made in the storyboard with tools given in the xcode (like the stepper, progress view, and etc) and when there's no internet connection, I want to access my coded viewcontroller that doesn't use the provided storyboard. How do I make the transition from the viewcontroller in the storyboard to the one not in the storyboard? Thanks!

UPDATE:Image depiction of what I seek to find: 
[depiction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuWiU.jpg)

Comment: post some code?

Comment: You're asking if you can instantiate a view controller in code and transition to it in code? Of course you can. Or you're asking whether you can choose between loading a view controller from a storyboard and instantiating a view controller in code? Of course you can.

Comment: So I have two xcode files. In one of them, I have a storyboard established through code with the following code: let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
//        layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout))

Comment: And on the other file, I just have the traditional way of launching the storyboard (I have one viewcontroller that launches in the Main.storyboard)

Comment: My question is: is there a way where I can, from the second file, I can transition into the viewcontroller of the first file. Don't worry about merging. I can just move the necessary files from the first file to the second file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you wanna do is show a storyboard programmatically?

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
window?.rootViewController = vc
```

Don't forget to add the "ViewController" identifier to the ViewController in your Interface builder.

Comment: If I have a file called NewController.swift and a class named NewController inside it, and I want to call this viewcontroller programmatically, then what would I do differently? Isn't the above answer just making an arbitrary instance of viewcontroller?

Comment: It's instantiating whatever VC you have on your Main storyboard. If you set the identifier of your "NewController" to ViewController it will show that one.

Comment: Is it possible to set the identifier of my "NewController" programmatically?

Comment: Why do you want to do it programmatically? You are using a storyboard. Identifiers are used to obtain references to IB viewcontrollers. I think there's an alternate method called instantiateInitialViewController, or something that gives you whichever is set to be the "root" vc inside your storyboard.

Comment: Because the viewController "NewController" have been coded, not hand-dragged using .storyboard, I can't go into .storyboard and set the identifier for the "NewController".

Comment: Then this question has nothing to do with storyboards, maybe you should search for show view controller from Nib ? or if there is no .storyboard just create an instance of it.

Comment: So I do have another viewcontroller file that is linked to storyboard. What I'm ultimately trying to do is: when there's internet connection, show the viewcontroller that's linked to the storyboard(because design of this viewcontroller was able to be achieved by using storyboard interface) and when there's no internet connection, I would like to show the NewController viewcontroller, which doesn't use storyboard.